# Finding specific element of table after ng-repeat is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have following html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 56px;"><strong style="font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Plan For {{entityYear}}</strong>
                <div class="input-group year date col-md-3" style="float: right;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="entityYear" ng-change="getPlansDataByYear(entityYear)">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-1">Name</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Description</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Start Date</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">End Date</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Date Added</th>
                    <th class="col-md-4">Chart</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="planRows" ng-repeat="plan in plansOfTheYear">
                    <td>
                        {{plan.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{plan.description}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{plan.startDate | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{plan.endDate | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{plan.dateAdded | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="doughnutChart{{$index}}" class="panel-body"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And controller code is following:

```
$scope.getPlansDataByYear = function(year){
        PlansService.getPlansDataByYear(year).success(function(data){
            $scope.plansOfTheYear = data;
            _.each(data, function(planData, index){
                $('#doughnutChart' + index).append('<div>Chart here</div>')
            });
        })
    }
```

What I want is find doughnutChart div and append `<div>Chart here</div>`. Problem is that because I use ajax call, it will run `ng-repeat` and also the jQuery line, thus it can't find for example first div `doughnutChart0` because it doesn't exists at the time when I try to find it with my jQuery line.

So my question is how I can first load the `ng-repeat` data, **then** search that specific div that I want to append data to? All help is really appreciated.

I have searched solution from stackoverflow and also angularjs documentation but couldn't find any.

When I run the code, it doesn't find any elements of that name. However I can find first row, since it exists already.

Comment: Are you using ui-router?

Comment: @br3w5: I don't use ui-router but I use ngRouter and $routeProvider. What it has to do with this?

Comment: First, it is not a good practice to do a `DOM` manipulation on angular app. In your case, since you are using `ng-repeat` to display data on the table? Why not binding the doughnutChart data to the `$scope.plansOfTheYear`? You can create a directive for create doughnutChart by passing corresponding data. Let me know what you think about this idea?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin: reason why I have to do it this because I need to build chart. This chart must be built using jQuery. The library I'm using to build this chart is called Chartjs and it has doughnut chart. I want to build for each row own doughnut chart.

Comment: There is a module for this called angualr-chart.js. Reactive, responsive, beautiful charts for AngularJS based on Chart.js http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ This is a wrapper for Chart.js but writing in angular way.

Comment: I didn't knew there is angular-chart. I could try this one and it looks more simplified.

Comment: Yeah, definitely give it a try, if you still want to use the original Chart.js, I can guide you how to do it.

Comment: I know how to use Chart.js because I have used it in my projects. That's not a problem. Now I try to find solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call your jQuery code after `ng-repeat` finished, just take advantage of JavaScript's single-threaded event loop and run your jQuery code after a timeout:

```
$scope.getPlansDataByYear = function(year){
  PlansService.getPlansDataByYear(year).success(function(data){
    $scope.plansOfTheYear = data;
    //you can use window.setTimeout instead of $timeout since angular doesn't need to be aware of the code run by jQuery
    window.setTimeout(function() {
     _.each(data, function(planData, index){
       $('#doughnutChart' + index).append('<div>Chart here</div>');
     });
   }, 1);

  });
};
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to do this the "angular way" I would suggest you change this in your view:

```
<td>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-bind-html="plan.chart"></div>
</td>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getPlansDataByYear = function(year){
  PlansService.getPlansDataByYear(year).success(function(data){
    $scope.plansOfTheYear = data;        
    $scope.plansOfTheYear.forEach(function(plan) {
      plan.chart = '<div>Chart here</div>';
    });
  });
};
```

Note that for this to work, you will need to include [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize).

Comment: Yes, creating a directive is even more "angular"  than adding sanitized HTML, but without enough details it would be hard to provide code for a directive.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend don't do it by append element this way, instead, you should try `directive`, angular will render the directive same time, so you don't have to worry about to append it by for-loop:

```
directive('chartattr', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: 'Chart here'
  };
});

<td>
<div id="doughnutChart{{$index}}" class="panel-body"></div>
<div chartattr></div>
</td>
```

[AngularJS Directive Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)